# Pandas Python read_csv error_bad_lines producing shell feedback

Tags: python, csv, pandas

This question may have an easy answer, but while reading in a very large csv file, there are lots of rows with an extra column. Based on the conditions of the dataset, I know that I can ignore those lines using `error_bad_lines = False`, however, when I do this, it reports every instance to the shell, which takes a lot of unnecessary and clutter. Is there a way to disable the report, or maybe configure pandas to accept those rows, but only the first three columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few parameters in `read_csv` that you should probably set.
For example, switching error_bad_lines and warn_bad_lines will turn off the stdout error messages.  If you only want to read the first three columns, set usecols as indicated below:

```
from pandas import read_csv

read_csv(filename, usecols=[0:3], error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: This worked for me, not sure what the problem was for Boud, but thanks

Comment: I edited my original post to correct the assignment of variables.

Comment: It worked for me after I changed my engine from C to python